# More Efficient For-Loop Calculation?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

Is there a more efficient way of writing the following? I current have this set up to calculate using a for-loop and at this pace, it will take a few days to compile.

I am forecasting demand over a period of 6 years on a weekly basis (52 weeks) broken down by product type (586 types) and zip code (892 unique ZIPs). The rand arrays are the parameter demand shares for each year drawn from a normal distribution and have dimensions [#weeks/#types/#zips x 6]. The demand growth array is the annual demand for each year.

I ultimately need to produce a data frame that has the following:
Year | Week of the Year | Product | Zip Code | Qty

This is what I currently have

```
demand_growth = [10,15,20,23,26,30]
rand_week_total = np.random.rand(52,6)
rand_product_total = np.random.rand(586,6)
rand_zipcode_total = np.random.rand(892,6)

forecast_year = []
forecast_week = []
forecast_product = []
forecast_ZIP = []
forecast_qty = []

for i in range(len(years)):
    for j in range(len(week)):
        for k in range(len(product)):
            for l in range(len(zipcode)):
                a = np.rint(demand_growth[i]*rand_week_total[j,i]*rand_product_total[k,i]*rand_zipcode_total[l,i])
                if a !=0:
                    forecast_year.append(years[i])
                    forecast_week.append(week[j])
                    forecast_product.append(product[k])
                    forecast_ZIP.append(zipcode[l])
                    forecast_qty.append(a)
```

'''
Edited: included examples of the arrays being multiplied

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what some of the variables/iterables in the line where you set `a` are defined as, but this seems to me like a problem ripe for Numpy and/or matrix multiplication. The main benefit here would be parallelizing the operations (which Numpy would do for you automatically).

Comment: I totally agree with @AndW, to reduce your for loop, you need to introduce some matrix multiplication between rand_week/product/zipcode_total. If possible, trying to use some sparse matrix to speed up your process if most of your data are useless

Comment: how would I do that? introduce a 3d matrix with week/product/zipcode and then reference that location? but then how could I go about recording the label for each cell (e.g. year 1, week 2, product B, zipcode 29681)?

Comment: also, edited to include an example of the rand_total arrays dimensions

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do more than than by studying how to use arrays and/or threading. For now, the best I got was 3x faster. I used lower boundaries to not spend the night on this.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def f1():
    demand_growth = np.array([10,15,20,23,26,30])
    rand_week_total = np.random.rand(52,6)
    rand_product_total = np.random.rand(23,6)
    rand_zipcode_total = np.random.rand(43,6)

    forecast_year = []
    forecast_week = []
    forecast_product = []
    forecast_ZIP = []
    forecast_qty = []

    years = np.array(range(2015, 2020))
    weeks = np.array(range(0, 52))
    product = np.array(range(0, 23))
    zipcode = np.array(range(0, 43))

    for i in range(len(years)):
        for j in range(len(weeks)):
            for k in range(len(product)):
                for l in range(len(zipcode)):
                    a = np.rint(demand_growth[i]*rand_week_total[j,i]*rand_product_total[k,i]*rand_zipcode_total[l,i])
                    if a !=0:
                        forecast_year.append(years[i])
                        forecast_week.append(weeks[j])
                        forecast_product.append(product[k])
                        forecast_ZIP.append(zipcode[l])
                        forecast_qty.append(a)

def f2():
    demand_growth = np.array([10,15,20,23,26,30])
    rand_week_total = np.random.rand(52,6)
    rand_product_total = np.random.rand(23,6)
    rand_zipcode_total = np.random.rand(43,6)

    forecast_year = []
    forecast_week = []
    forecast_product = []
    forecast_ZIP = []
    forecast_qty = []

    years = np.array(range(2015, 2020))
    weeks = np.array(range(0, 52))
    product = np.array(range(0, 23))
    zipcode = np.array(range(0, 43))

    for i in range(len(years)):
        for j in range(len(weeks)):
            temp_ij = demand_growth[i]*rand_week_total[j,i]
            for k in range(len(product)):
                temp_ikj = temp_ij*rand_product_total[k,i]
                for l in range(len(zipcode)):
                    a = np.rint(temp_ikj*rand_zipcode_total[l,i])
                    if a !=0:
                        forecast_year.append(years[i])
                        forecast_week.append(weeks[j])
                        forecast_product.append(product[k])
                        forecast_ZIP.append(zipcode[l])
                        forecast_qty.append(a)

def f3():
    demand_growth = np.array([10,15,20,23,26,30])
    rand_week_total = np.random.rand(52,6)
    rand_product_total = np.random.rand(23,6)
    rand_zipcode_total = np.random.rand(43,6)

    forecast_year = []
    forecast_week = []
    forecast_product = []
    forecast_ZIP = []
    forecast_qty = []

    years = np.array(range(2015, 2020))
    weeks = np.array(range(0, 52))
    product = np.array(range(0, 23))
    zipcode = np.array(range(0, 43))

    for j in range(len(weeks)):
        temp_j = demand_growth*rand_week_total[j,:]
        for k in range(len(product)):
            temp_jk = temp_j * rand_product_total[k,:]
            for l in range(len(zipcode)):
                a = np.rint(temp_jk*rand_zipcode_total[l,:])
                for i in range(len(years)):
                    if a[i] !=0:
                        forecast_year.append(years[i])
                        forecast_week.append(weeks[j])
                        forecast_product.append(product[k])
                        forecast_ZIP.append(zipcode[l])
                        forecast_qty.append(a[i])


print(timeit.Timer(f1).timeit(5))
print(timeit.Timer(f2).timeit(5))
print(timeit.Timer(f3).timeit(5))
```